# Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type '…

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm really confused here. Can you please help me? See the codes;

I'm trying to build a structure for my solution which is use only one repository. To query specific queries i use IQueryBuilder. Actually i was looking for a good smaple for Object Querying and i found this one [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23404.creating-a-repository-with-a-fluent-interface.aspx)

```
public interface IQueryBuilder<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryBuilder<T> Include(Expression<Func<T, object>> path);
    IQueryBuilder<T> OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> path);
    IQueryBuilder<T> OrderByDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> path);
    IQueryBuilder<T> Page(int page, int pageSize);

    T FirstOrDefault();
    Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    List<T> ToList();
    Task<List<T>> ToListAsync();

    int Count();
    Task<int> CountAsync();
}
```

The Repository codes here.

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
}
```

So far so good for me. I was very very happy until pressing F6 and i get below error because of Query in repository interface.

Warning 1   Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'IRepository' IRepository.cs  13  32  VideoK2.Repository

By the way there are a few questions about this topic. But i couldnt understood them. Couldnt figure out about my topic. So, sorry for asking again.

Comment: Essentially, one of your "subclasses" defines a generic type name that shadows one from a superclass. In essence, it's adding ambiguity to the use of the name `T`.

Comment: Is this C#?  If so, please add that tag to your question.

Answer (score 10):

The compiler sees this definition as ambiguous:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
}
```

To realize why, ask yourself this example question (I'll use two randomly chosen classes): if you have an instance of `IRepository<string>`, should you be able to call `Query<StreamReader>` on it?

If the answer is yes, this means that the type parameter `T` of the method `Query<T>` isn't the same as the type parameter `T` of the interface `IRepository<T>`. They are two independent type parameters. If this is the case, then just change one of the two to something else, to make your intention clear:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    IQueryBuilder<TResult> Query<TResult>() where TResult : class;
}
```

If the answer is no, this means that the type parameter `T` of the interface `IRepository<T>` dictates the return type of the method `Query`. If this is the case, then the method shouldn't declare its own type parameter, because the type already has the information.

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable 
    where T : class
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Query();
}
```

Comment: The compiler is definitely not confused, but the user is ;) Anyway, good explanation.

Answer (score 7):

This code:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Can be basically rewritten to:

```
public interface IRepository<TObject> : IDisposable
{
    IQueryBuilder<TResult> Query<TResult>() where TResult : class;
}
```

To get rid of the error. The issue is that the second `<T>` shadows the first one.

**But...** do you see the problem with this new code?

---

I guess what you really mean is either this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> : IDisposable
    where T : class
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Query();
}
```

Or this:

```
public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Query<T>() where T : class;
}
```

Keeping both generic parameters doesn't make much sense in this context, because one of them is never used.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. After the answers i saw the right way. The reason of i use Generic Repository and Object Query is i want to use one repository for all queries. So this forced me to use Generic Repository. (Because of my previous exercises). But in this sample using generic repository is not required.

I want to write some codes for futher information.

This interface for Object Query

```
public interface IQueryBuilder<T>
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    IQueryBuilder<T> Include(Expression<Func<T, object>> path);
    IQueryBuilder<T> OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> path);
    IQueryBuilder<T> OrderByDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> path);
    IQueryBuilder<T> Page(int page, int pageSize);

    T FirstOrDefault();
    Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    List<T> ToList();
    Task<List<T>> ToListAsync();

    int Count();
    Task<int> CountAsync();
}
```

and its implementation

```
public class QueryBuilder<T> : IQueryBuilder<T>
{
    DdContext applicationDbContext;
    private IQueryable<T> query;

    public QueryBuilder(DbContext applicationDbContext)
    {
        this.applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
        this.query = this.context.Set<T>();
    }

    public IQueryBuilder<T> Where(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        this.query = this.query.Where(predicate);

        return this;
    }

    public IQueryBuilder<T> Include(Expression<Func<T, object>> path)
    {
        this.query = this.query.Include(path);
        return this;
    }

    public IQueryBuilder<T> OrderBy(Expression<Func<T, object>> path)
    {
        this.query = this.query.OrderBy(path);
        return this;
    }

    public IQueryBuilder<T> OrderByDescending(Expression<Func<T, object>> path)
    {
        this.query = this.query.OrderByDescending(path);
        return this;
    }

    public IQueryBuilder<T> Page(int page, int pageSize)
    {
        this.query = this.query.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        return this;
    }

    public T FirstOrDefault()
    {
        return this.query.FirstOrDefault<T>();
    }

    public Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync()
    {
        return this.query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }

    public List<T> ToList()
    {
        return this.query.ToList();
    }

    public Task<List<T>> ToListAsync()
    {
        return this.query.ToListAsync();
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return this.query.Count();
    }

    public Task<int> CountAsync()
    {
        return this.query.CountAsync();
    }
}
```

This is Repository interface

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IQueryBuilder<T> Query<T>();
}
```

and its implementation

```
public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private DBContext Contex { get; set; }

    public Repository(DBContext ctx)
    {
        this.Contex = ctx;
    }

    public QueryBuilder.IQueryBuilder<T> Query<T>()
    {
        return new QueryBuilder.QueryBuilder<T>(this.Contex);
    }
}
```

and these lines are sample usages

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    private IRepository repo = new Repository(new SampleContext());

    public HomeController(){}

    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var author = repo.Query<Author>().ToList();

        var authors = repo.Query<Author>().ToListAsync();

        var authors = repo.Query<Author>().Where(a => a.Name != "Orwell").ToList();

        var authors = repo.Query<Author>().Where(a => a.Name != "Orwell").ToListAsync();

        var author = repo.Query<Author>().FirstOrDefault();

        var author = repo.Query<Author>().FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        var author = repo.Query<Author>().Where(a => a.Name == "Orwell").FirstOrDefault();

        var author = repo.Query<Author>().Where(a => a.Name == "Orwell").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        var book = repo.Query<Book>().Where(b => b.Title == "The Wasp Factory").FirstOrDefault();

        return View(author);
    }
}
```